# myFile undeclared identifier

Tags: fstream

I get the following error when i try to solve my file:

```
myFile undeclared identifier
```

Help would be appreciated! :) I really dont see what is the problem is in this code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>


int main()
{
    ofstream myFile;
    std::string name;
    std::string password;
    std::cout << "Enter Name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Enter password" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> password;
    std::string info = name + ":" + password;
    myFile.open ("Database.txt");
    myFile << (info) << std::endl << ;
    myFile.close();
    Sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You sould use :   `std::ofstream myFile` to declare `myFile`

or you can add `using namespace std;` at the top of the programm (outside the main) and remove all `std::`.

If you want to add text to "Database.txt", you sould use :

```
myFile.open("Database.txt", ios::app);
```

Something is wrong :

```
myFile << (info) << std::endl << ;
```

You sould'nt keep the last `<<`

You also may want to return something in your main.